# Caption on photos

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I want to overlay a caption to different sorts of media (images, gifs, videos). Essentially add a white bar on top or bottom of the image and then write in some text. Then save the image/video to firebase as a new image with the caption added to it.

Does anyone know of any useful packages or tutorials that could help me do this?

Comment: You can use GridTile for showing an image with text on the head or foot. For your actual goal, I think the process is a bit complex.

Comment: Especially, if you want this to be automatic.

Answer (score -1):

There are some dart packages I can list so that they will help you:
[Image editor pro](https://pub.dev/packages/image_editor_pro)

For storing them in firebase i can list you another package:
[Firebase picture uploader](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_picture_uploader)